# Go appengine examples throw exceptions

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I am unable to get the go examples working that come with the app-engine package.

According to the docs I should be able to run:

```
cd google_appengine
dev_appserver.py helloworld
```

Everything seems to startup fine as shown by the below terminal output:

```
WARNING  2012-10-01 04:32:09,023 rdbms_mysqldb.py:74] The rdbms API is not available     because the MySQLdb library could not be loaded.
INFO     2012-10-01 04:32:09,077 appcfg.py:585] Checking for updates to the SDK.
INFO     2012-10-01 04:32:09,728 appcfg.py:603] The SDK is up to date.
INFO     2012-10-01 04:32:09,746 dev_appserver_multiprocess.py:655] Running application dev~helloworld on port 8080: http://localhost:8080
INFO     2012-10-01 04:32:09,746 dev_appserver_multiprocess.py:657] Admin console is available at: http://localhost:8080/_ah/admin
```

But when I try to view the page being served on localhost:8080 I get:

```
<type 'exceptions.Exception'>: ('no .go files in %s', '/home/chris/.google_appengine/demos/helloworld') 
  args = ('no .go files in %s', '/home/chris/.google_appengine/demos/helloworld') 
  message = ''
```

This is correct there are no go files in demos/helloworld, but are instead in demos/helloworld/helloworld (this is their folder structure not mine).  I tried just moving the file to the parent folder, but that doesn't work.

This is a fresh install of go (1.0.3) and appengine.

BTW this happens for all the examples in the demo folder.

Any ideas?

Comment: I am not familiar with app engine, but have you set your [GOPATH](http://code.google.com/p/go-wiki/wiki/GOPATH)?

Comment: This could be related to something I'm not familiar with, but is there a reason that `google_appengine` has a `.` before it?

Comment: I'm confused by your terminal session. Do you mean: `cd google_appengine ; dev_appserver.py demos/helloworld`

That works for me on a fresh copy of App Engine SDK 1.7.2.

Comment: @RocketDonkey: google_appengine is just a hidden folder, but after changing it, that seemed to be the issue.

Comment: @chris: awesome, so all is good now? If so, happy it helped!

Answer (score 2):

did you try this?

```
cd google_appengine
./dev_appserver.py demos/helloworld
```